# Upgraded WampServer, now can't start MySQL

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I moved my WampServer www and SQL/data to Dropbox, and WampServer was working fine like this.

I noticed I was using an old version of WampServer on my desktop, while using the latest version of WampServer on my laptop.

I uninstalled WampServer on my desktop, and installed `wampserver3.0.6_x86_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10` on my desktop.

I edited `my.ini`: `datadir="D:/Dropbox/WAMP/SQL"`

When I load `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` in my browser, I attempt to login, but receive the error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. — The server is not responding (or the local server's
>   socket is not correctly configured).

If I check `C:\wamp\logs\mysql.log` I see:

```
wampmysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2017-04-15T11:43:23.372042Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2017-04-15T11:43:23.373043Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2017-04-15T11:43:23.378046Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2017-04-15T11:43:23.384551Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2017-04-15T11:43:23.386553Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

If I look in the folder `D:\Dropbox\WAMP\SQL\data\mysql`, I see the files:

- plugin.frm
- plugin.MYD
- plugin.MYI
- user.frm
- user.MYD
- user.MYI

If I run the following in a `cmd` window:

`C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin> mysql_upgrade.exe`

I receive the error:

> mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'localhost' (10061) while connecting to the MySQL server Upgrade
>   process encountered error and will not continue.

If I go to `System Tray > Wamp > MySQL > Version`, I see only one option: `5.7.14`.

If I try to start MySQL from Wamp icon, or `services.msc`, it won't start, and the errors above repeat.

**Update**: if I run `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` on my laptop, which uses www and SQL data in Dropbox too, phpMyAdmin produces no error, and detects the databases fine, and lists them down the left hand side.

What do I need to do from here?

Comment: So what version of MYSQL is on the laptop

Comment: What version of MYSQL is on the PC

Comment: @RiggsFolly `5.7.14` on both.